# Could I use a solenoid to push a wire, without the solenoid's electromagnetism affecting the wire? (or vice versa)

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid

If I have a solenoid, and I put current through it, it would push a metal rod. This rod would be inside of the coil, and have a casing (to not damage the coil).

Something like this image on google:
[image: 1]

I was wondering if, instead of the metal rod, I could have a wire, that carries a similar electrical current (to the solenoid's current).

Maybe this would be possible if I used a transistor gain circuit to amplify the current of the solenoid, so I could keep the current of the wire low, and the solenoid relatively high (so it doesn't have as much of an affect). (I could also add a resistor to the wire going throuh the solenoid. It would have a similar affect)

Would it be possible to do this?

Comment: The rod would have to be made of a ferromagnetic material (iron, nickel, cobalt, or some alloys), but I don't see any reason you couldn't do this. That said, I also don't see any reason you would *want* to do this; I suspect this might be an X-Y problem.

Comment: What is an X-Y problem?

Comment: I was wondering if the currents could somehow affect each other, I'm not really an electromagnetism expert.

Comment: An X-Y problem is when you ask about a solution Y to problem X, but you don't know enough about X to see why Y is a poor solution in the first place, and should just ask about X. For example, note that not any material is "pushed" by the solenoid, nor just any current flow in such a wire (it needs to be a solenoid as well). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @TimWilliams (I know about variable reistors) I was trying to make a way to increase the resistance of a wire, given an outside current. In this case, the more current going through the solenoid, the farther the reistive rod would be pushed, the longer the path the electrons have to flow through, the more reistance. (This was just an idea)

Comment: Then you should ask _that_, or you should specifically ask if the resistance of a wire is changed by operating it in a magnetic field (answer: not appreciably, for most materials, but Google "magnetoresistance").

Comment: @Walter There are motor-operated potentiometers; is that what you want?

Comment: @Hearth that is kind of what I was thinking. But do you know if an electromagnet will affect an wire that already has current going through it? **Is there an equation that represents the change in voltage of a wire nearby to an electromagnet?**

Comment: @Walter Yes, you can derive it from Maxwell's equations. I still don't think you're asking what you actually want, though.